# SyntaxError for import in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am somewhat new to Node and I am running an extremely simple example from https://javascript.info/import-export in Node (10.17.0) to check the import functionality.

function.js

```
export function sayHi(user) {                                               
    alert('Hello, ${user}!');
}
```

I am calling this with:

say.js

```
import {sayHi} from './function.js';                                        

sayHi('Mike');
```

but for some reason when I run (on the command line)

```
node say.js
```

it returns

```
import {sayHi} from './function.js';
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

It is probably very basic, but I can't see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you enable ES6 imports? https://timonweb.com/posts/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are importing is `Typescript` way but node doesn't support Typescript,
unless you write typescript and compile it to JavaScript.

Change your `import` like this

```
const sayHi=require('./function.js')
```